# Oracle String Date to date getting back last 7 days

Tags: sql, oracle, date, oracle11g

I have very large data set I am querying. Over 90 million rows. I am trying to limit the data by the last 7 days but am having trouble with the Oracle syntax. The DB is Oracle 11g

The date field is called START_UTC_DAY it is a string and looks like 20200414

I have tried

```
 SELECT TO_DATE(START_UTC_DAY, 'YYYYMMDD')
FROM SOURCETABLE
WHERE START_UTC_DAY > SysDate - 7
```

I get the ORA-01861 Literal does not match format string

Forgive my ignorance, my SQL is rudimentary and I am learning as I go.

Comment: What is the data type of column `START_UTC_DAY`?

Comment: `DESC SOURCETABLE;` and paste the output, or at least the line which has `START_UTC_DAY` showing its data type.

Comment: Why are you storing date values in a `varchar` column? That is a **really**, really bad idea

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I wish I knew. There are three rather large Oracle DB's we currently have that all data is stored as VARCHAR, while several Postgres and MySQL DB's all have clearly defined data types.

Only excuse I can see is these are mammoth systems built by a third party many years ago. We got what we paid for and it has worked for over a decade.

Reason I keep being brought into it, seems they keep asking me to update/revise processes from this archaic DB to our soon to be  cloud data lake and DB's .

A lucky position as I get to sharpen my SQL and AWS tool set!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT TO_DATE(START_UTC_DAY, 'YYYYMMDD')
FROM SOURCETABLE
WHERE TO_DATE(START_UTC_DAY, 'YYYYMMDD') > SysDate - 7
```

`TO_DATE()` in the `WHERE` clause converts the string value with the given format model to a DATE type before comparing it to another DATE value thus avoiding the implicit conversion which caused you the issue. See comments for a better variation.

The message here is avoid implicit conversions.

Explanation:

The error was due to implicit conversion in the WHERE clause, a comparison between two values of different data types.

[**2.2.8.2 Implicit Data Conversion**](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/20/sqlrf/Data-Type-Comparison-Rules.html#GUID-98BE3A78-6E33-4181-B5CB-D96FD9DC1694)

- When comparing a character value with a DATE value, Oracle
  converts the character data to DATE.

During the conversion, the character value/string literal is evaluated against a date format model that depends on the following setting.

```
select name, value from v$parameter where name = 'nls_date_format';
```

In my database it returns,

```
NAME                 VALUE               
-------------------- --------------------
nls_date_format      DD-MON-YY
```

This setting can be changed at the level of a session and that will produce various results as shown below.

Here are some tests to further explain the behavior using SQL Developer using a new session.

```
SQL> show parameter nls_date_format;
NAME            TYPE   VALUE     
--------------- ------ --------- 
nls_date_format string DD-MON-YY 


SQL> 
select str from 
(select '20200412' as str from dual)
where str <> sysdate;

...
Error report -
ORA-01861: literal does not match format string


SQL> 
alter session set nls_date_format = 'ddmmyyyy';

Session altered.

SQL> 
SQL> show parameter nls_date_format;
NAME            TYPE   VALUE    
--------------- ------ -------- 
nls_date_format string ddmmyyyy 


SQL> 
select str from 
(select '20200412' as str from dual)
where str <> sysdate;

...
Error report -
ORA-01843: not a valid month


SQL> 
alter session set nls_date_format = 'fxyyyy-mm-dd';

Session altered.

SQL> 
SQL> show parameter nls_date_format;
NAME            TYPE   VALUE        
--------------- ------ ------------ 
nls_date_format string fxyyyy-mm-dd 


SQL> 
select str from 
(select '20200412' as str from dual)
where str <> sysdate;

...
Error report -
ORA-01861: literal does not match format string


SQL> 
alter session set nls_date_format = 'yyyymmdd';

Session altered.

SQL> 
SQL> show parameter nls_date_format;
NAME            TYPE   VALUE    
--------------- ------ -------- 
nls_date_format string yyyymmdd 


SQL> 
select str from 
(select '20200412' as str from dual)
where str <> sysdate;

STR     
--------
20200412
```

As shown above, the same query ends up producing different "results" depending on the `nls_date_format` setting.

Comment: Might be nice to add a little explanation.

Comment: Using `WHERE START_UTC_DAY > TO_CHAR(SysDate - 7, 'YYYYMMDD')` might provide better performance.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit, Thanks for pointing that out. I did not consider that aspect.

Comment: Thank you this worked well. I keep forgetting how explicit SQL, especially Oracle, is in this aspect. In other programming languages I use, if I declared it a date I then don't have to keep re-declaring it a date in other statements.

Like I mentioned Rookie SQL. I appreciate your assistance and that of this community greatly.

Answer (score 1):

> The date field is called START_UTC_DAY it is a string and looks like 20200414

When you say date looks like `20200414` doesn't mean it's a string, it just means that your **locale-specific NLS settings** are set to display the date in that format. But it isn't actually stored in any format.

> I get the ORA-01861 Literal does not match format string

That's because you are using **TO_DATE on a date**, therefore forcing Oracle to convert the DATE into string based on the NLS dependent format, and then converting back to date using the format you mentioned. This causes `ORA-01861 Literal does not match format string` error.

Never use `TO_DATE` on a date column, use `TO_CHAR` to display it in the format you desire:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(START_UTC_DAY, 'YYYYMMDD')
FROM SOURCETABLE
WHERE START_UTC_DAY > SYSDATE -7;
```

Also, remember DATE also has time portion up to seconds. In case you only want the date portion without time, you need to use `TRUNC(SYSDATE)`.

Comment: I don't think column `START_UTC_DAY` is a `DATE` data type. `NLS_DATE_FORMAT = YYYYMMDD` is possible but rather unlikely.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit, while TO may have said the column "is a string", keep in mind that many, many people get this fine point confused. And given that he also said "my SQL is rudimentary and I am learning as I go." I really wouldn't put much faith in the accuracy of the statement that the column is a string.  Hence, we _really_ need to see the table def.  Lacking that, I think the behavior of his query, and the error, tend to suggest the column is really a DATE, and is simply being mis-handled by the beginners use of TO_DATE.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit `ORA-01861` is likely due to TO_DATE on a date. But, if OP comes back saying `START_UTC_DAY` is actually a string then my answer needs to change. But OP doesn't seem to be confident in his statements, so it's likely that the column is a DATE type.

Comment: In the DB I am referencing, every data type comes back when using DESC SOURCE TABLE as VARCHAR

So you can see where  my use of SQL is almost always a challenge. That single table I am asking about is 300 columns and over 90 million rows. Getting down to just 7 days of a specific few rows is very important to performance and allowing me to test and tune my queries with greater efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want `TO_CHAR()` rather than `TO_DATE()`:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(START_UTC_DAY, 'YYYYMMDD')
FROM SOURCETABLE
WHERE START_UTC_DAY > SysDate - 7;
```

Note that `sysdate` has a time component.  So, you might want:  `trunc(sysdate) - interval '7' day` (I prefer the explicit `interval` syntax).